# How to delete a youngest person from a list with function?

Tags: python

I need a program that would let a person enter a person's name and his birth year (5 people only).
The information is written into two lists - one with names and the other with years.
Then the program needs to remove the youngest person (or youngest people).
The final result needs to be printed out in a .txt file.

This is what I have so far:

```
names = []
ages = []


def names_ages():
    while True:
        name_age = input("Enter your name and birth year: ")
        name_age.split()
        print(name_age)
```

I don't know if I'm going into the right direction or not, could somebody suggest something?

Comment: delete youngest person from a list - Okay, you should start with creating a list.

Comment: Right direction? You are not even going anywhere. You need to store it first after splitting it and please give us extra information that how is the birth date format? You entering only the first name or first and last name. Because split method will depend on it

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are expecting first name and the year to be separated by a space like so.

```
"andrew 1996"
```

if so, you are going to want to split the input on space (to have the first entry correspond to "andrew" and the second to correspond to "1996"

```
response = name_age.split(" ")
```

Now you can add these values to the arrays that you defined up above (or you could use a python dictionary which I think would be better suited for this problem) https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
names.append(response[0])
ages.append(int(response[1]))
```

You are going to have to decide when to stop accepting names, which you would put in your while loop condition(right now it is running forever) Perhaps wait until the user input is "stop" or something of that nature.

That should get you in the correct direction, comment if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

```
name = []
year = []
x=0
while x <3:
    x += 1
    user = name.append(raw_input("enter name"))
    user_year = year.append(raw_input("enter DOB"))
o = []
for i in zip(year,name):
    o.append(i)
o.sort()
o.remove(o[0])
print o
```

This might one from of the solutions from many possible.